# Can we Override DBContext2 object to DBContext1 object at Compile time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Basically, we have developed a framework that provides common features like Email Service feature, Lookup Management, User Modules, etc. In this framework, the DB Context is inherited by the `FrameworkContext` class for data access operations.

Moreover, we have our own private `NuGet` repository where all the framework packages are available for installation in the new projects. As per the scenario, when I installed those packages in the new application, I have to create another Context class for client project which is the new application in this scenario.

But I would like to use only one context class which is shared in the whole application including framework source code as you can see in the `BaseService` class implementation.

Our goal is to pass all the object to the `BaseService` class which is responsible for the object creation. One thing more, the shared context will provide me the transaction to manage all the calling services. I need good suggestions that can solve my problem.

No, I didn't try anything yet.

1 : 
ABC.dll downloaded from the NuGet packages.

```
public class FrameworkContext : DbContext { 
 public virtual DbSet<FrameworkTable> FrameworkTable{ get; set; }
}
```

2 :

```
public class ClientContext : FrameworkContext  { 
 public virtual DbSet<ClientTable> ClientTable{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I have all the virtual properties in the derived class. But I cannot pass this object to base service which is :

```
public abstract class BaseService {

     private readonly NeedToConfirmType _context;

     public NeedToConfirmType Context { get { return _context; } }

     public BaseService (NeedToConfirmType context) { _context = context;}
}
```

There are two scenarios in the above code. Whenever I would pass Framework context to the base service, it should behave like that. But when I want to use client context, it should allow me to perform database operations as per Client context.

I would like to have a solution where the change does not impair on the existing code snippet. Can I inject Derived class properties at compile-time because at run time it does not allow me to use those properties in the particular service?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's Old School, but how about an interface?

```cs
public interface IClientContext
{
    DbSet<ClientTable> ClientTable { get; set; }
}

public class ClientContext : FrameworkContext, IClientContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<ClientTable> ClientTable { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseService
{
    private readonly FrameworkContext _context;
    public FrameworkContext Context { get { return _context; } }
    public BaseService(FrameworkContext context) { _context = context; }
    public void DoSomethingToClientTable()
    {
        if (_context is IClientContext)
        {
            var clientTable = ((IClientContext)_context).ClientTable;
            //Do something interesting here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BaseService class is not accessible in the client application. It comes from the nuget packages which is the dll in my case